# How to not get related data in Entity Framework

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have the following scenario.

I have one table in the database *A* that contains a lot of entries. This table is lightweight and only have a bit of data for each entry.

Another table *B* has a many to one relationship with *A*, and can contain lots of data.

I have a client and a server in my application that communicates using WCF.

My problem is that when the client calls a method on the server that should return all the *A*'s, I get much more data than I need to. On the server I basically have a single line of code:

```
return entityContext.A.ToList();
```

My problem is that on the client, if I debug and inspect the returned collection, each element has the property *B* populated with all the data from the expensive table.

I only needed the basic data from the *A* table to show a list on the client, but ended up sending a ton of data over the wire.

So the question is, how can I make the server ignore the *B* table when I fetch the data to send to the client. Basically, I need something like the oposite of `Include`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn off lazy loading. It can be done either through designer or in code by calling:

```
entityContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```